# the probabiltiy of simultaneity

Tags: probability

Suppose There's 5 black balls and 4 white balls in the box. And I want to pick up the 2 black balls. There's two ways to picking the ball. First, you pick the ball one by one. Second you pick the ball completely simultaneous.

In this situation, I think the probability of the first is (5/9)*(4/8)= 0.27777
And In second situation, the probability is (5/9)*(5/9)= 0.30864. The reason why i think like this way is that before picking the ball, the probability of each ball being black is 5/9. So If you pick the ball completely simultaneous, the probability will be (5/9)*(5/9). Am I correct? Tell me your idea.

P.S Sorry for my english skill.

Comment: There are two ways of picking the balls: *with replacement* and *without replacement*.   To get your $\frac{5}{9}\times \frac{5}{9}$ result you need *with replacement*.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong.

In simultaneous case, it should be $\Large{5\choose2}\over\Large{9\choose2}$ which is the same number as $({5\over9})({4\over8})$.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of picking two black balls is $\tfrac 59{\cdot}\tfrac 59$ only if it is *possible* that both balls picked can be the exact same ball.

This is permissible when picking with replacement.   It is never permissible when picking without replacement, no matter how close to simultaneous the selection is made.

If you must select two distinct balls, the probability they are both black is: $\tfrac 5 9{\cdot}\tfrac 4 8$

---

In fact, for this calculation the order of selection is not important.

When selecting balls without replacement, the probability that the *second* ball drawn will be black is $\tfrac 5 9$.   After all, any of the nine balls has an equal probability of being drawn second, and there are five black balls.

Similarly the conditional probability that the *first* ball drawn will be black, if it is given that the *second* ball drawn *will be* black, is $\tfrac 4 8$.

---

To put it another way: Conditional Probability has *nothing* to do with the timing of the events.

It is about placing conditions on measurement; in this case the probability that a ball is black, when there is a ball in the box that it cannot be.

The probability that your *left* hand and *right* hand both pick black balls is the product of the probability that your left hand picks a black ball, and the conditional probability that your right hand picks a black ball given that your left hand does.
$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(L\cap R) & = \mathsf P(L)\cdot\mathsf P(R\mid L)\\[1ex] & = \tfrac 5 9 \cdot \tfrac 4 8\end{align}$$
It does not matter if your left hand picks the ball *before* your right, *after* your right, or they do so simultaneously.   The measures are the same.